# Funcion de javascript no me refresca el dato muy bien

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hola buenas tardes amigo mi problema es que yo uso un select option el cual si escojo que si me debe esconder un boton y un select y tambien si es NA pero si es NO me los muestra entonces use una funcion de javascript y funciona muy bien pero digamos yo escojo si y luego es cojo no y luego escojo NA y otravez escojo no no me carga la funcion de javascript no refresca este es mi codigo

```
$(document).delegate('.txtFormulario_Pregunta', 'change', function(event) {
        var valor = $(this).val();

        var idPre = $(this).attr('id').replace('txtFormulario_Pregunta_', '');




        if (valor === 'NO'){
            if ($('#txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre).length === 0){


                $(this).parent('div').parent('div').append(tds);
                $('#btnagregartecins_inc_' + idPre).show();
                $('#txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre).show();
                $('#txt_tec_ins_inc_' + idPre).show();
                $('#btnagregartecinc' + idPre).show();




    var tds = '<br><textarea class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="OBSERVACIÓN:" id="txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre + '"></textarea>';




                    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').append(tds);
                    $('#txtFormulario_Conformidad').val('NO');
                } else{
                    $('#txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre).remove();

                }
            }

            else{

                if (valor === 'SI') {


                    $('#btnagregartecins_inc_' + idPre).hide();
                    $('#txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre).hide();
                    $('#txt_tec_ins_inc_' + idPre).hide();
                    $('#btnagregartecinc' + idPre).hide();

            }


                if (valor === 'NA') {


                    $('#btnagregartecins_inc_' + idPre).hide();
                    $('#txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre).hide();
                    $('#txt_tec_ins_inc_' + idPre).hide();
                    $('#btnagregartecinc' + idPre).hide();

            }
            }

        });
```

y mi html es este

```
tds += "<select class='txtFormulario_Pregunta' id='txtFormulario_Pregunta_" + val.idPre + "' rel='" + val.idPre + "'>";
tds += "<option disabled selected>Seleccione</option>";
tds += "<option value='SI'>SI</option>";
tds += "<option value='NO'>NO</option>";
tds += "<option value='NA'>N.A</option>";
tds += "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una posible solución a tu problema, junto con algunas recomendaciones:

**Primero:**

```
// Agregue el attributo data-pre para obtener el id más facil
tds += "<select class='txtFormulario_Pregunta' data-pre='" + val.idPre + "' id='txtFormulario_Pregunta_" + val.idPre + "' rel='" + val.idPre + "'>";
tds += "<option hidden>Seleccione</option>";
tds += "<option value='SI'>SI</option>";
tds += "<option value='NO'>NO</option>";
tds += "<option value='NA'>N.A</option>";
tds += "</select>";
```

**Luego:**

```
// .delegate(..), es una versión antigua de .on()
// por lo tanto no se recomienda su uso
$(document).on('.txtFormulario_Pregunta', 'change', function(event) {
    var valor = $(this).val();
    var idPre = $(this).data('pre'); // El nuevo atributo que agregue al select

    if (valor === 'NO'){
        if ($('#txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre).length === 0){
            $(this).parent('div').parent('div').append(tds);
            $('#btnagregartecins_inc_' + idPre).show();
            $('#txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre).show();
            $('#txt_tec_ins_inc_' + idPre).show();
            $('#btnagregartecinc' + idPre).show();

            var tds = '<br><textarea class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="OBSERVACIÓN:" id="txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre + '"></textarea>';

            $(this).parent('div').parent('div').append(tds);
            $('#txtFormulario_Conformidad').val('NO');
        }
    } else{
        // Aquí solo necesitas especificarlo una vez
        // puesto que es la misma acción de ocultar si el valor es "SI" o "NA"
        $('#btnagregartecins_inc_' + idPre).hide();
        $('#txt_tec_ins_inc_' + idPre).hide();
        $('#btnagregartecinc' + idPre).hide();

        // Remover el elemento para que se cree uno nuevo cada que se 
        // seleccione la opción "NO"
        $('#txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre).remove();
    }
});
```

No pude hacer un test, pero si surge algún error solo comenta cual es y lo revisamos.

Comment: nu amigo ese no me sirvio me quedo igual no me devolvio :(